# How to create user a service which takes JWT token and returns user object

Tags: javascript, java, angular, spring

I have 3 services

- angular (frontend)
- java (fapi)
- java (backend, jpa)

Every user's request consists of header `<Authentification>` with a JWT Token(interceptor in angular) key.

How can I get user from this token, for example to create users page? Or will admin understand this is user or not?

I'm trying to save  `Map(key,value)` pairs (token,user) in my front, but this map deleted every time.

Do I need to create this Map in fapi? Or save token in database?

Comment: please add more details about your issue add some code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the user logs in, you can include the user's "username" along with the "token" as your response from the backend. Then you can save the {token, username} you receive from the backend into **localStorage** in your frontend

Sample:

```
// Response from backend--------------------
{
    "token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9",
    "username": "tester"
}

// Login service from frontend--------------------
login(user: User): Observable<User> {
    return this.http.post<User>('/login', user)
        .pipe(
            map(response => {
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response));
                return response;
            })
        );
}
```

Then if you want to retrieve the {token, username} from your frontend:

```
const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
```

Answer (score 0):

When the user logs in, the token can either be stored in the local storage or in the cookies.

The token will only contain encrypted data that you put in. If you need the user’s username from a token, you need to include the username when creating the token.